# How to refresh the list in KnockoutJs after it is loaded first time?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, custom-component, knockout-3.0, knockout-binding-handlers

I am displaying data list as shown below:

```
<div class="my-table" data-bind="if:(dataList() && dataList().length)">
//render data raw here...
```

I am new to ko and looking to refresh this list without reloading the page, is this something possible with knockout?

I believe i can add new items to the list using something like `applyBindingsToNode`, but looking for a way to refresh the entire list as there are some refreshed numbers on one of the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be unclear on the basics of [Observable Arrays](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html).

You can assign a new array value to `dataList` by passing the array as an argument: `dataList(['one', 'two', 'three'])`;

You can modify the contents of `dataList` using most of the usual array-updating functions: push, pop, shift, unshift, reverse, and sort. There are also replace and remove functions, which are not standard array-updating functions.

Any updates you make to `dataList` using these methods will be reflected in your view, assuming your commented "render data raw here" section makes use of `dataList`.